# RxJava asynchronous alternative to doOnNext

Tags: rx-java

I want to make long operation with RxJava while not blocking consuming them on subscribe method (or otherwise). longOperation() is just saving value in DB so it can't affect value itself. I have following code:

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .doOnNext { 
              value -> longOperation(value)
           }
          .subscribe {
              finalConsumer(it)  
           }
```

How can  make it asynchronous?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flatMap` and `subscribeOn`:

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .flatMap(value ->
      Completable.fromAction(() ->
        longOperation(value))
      .toObservable()
      .subscribeOn(Scheduler.io()))
  .subscribe {
     subscriber  
  }
```

You may also wish to constrain the scheduler by substituting `Schedulers.io()` with `Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n))`.

Comment: `finalConsumer(it)` will never be called since you flatMap the original value into an Observable that never emits anything.
Also, this solution would make us wait for `longOperation` to complete before `finalConsumer` executes, which sounds like what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Yeah I didn't pay much attention to the finalConsumer stuff but the same technique is used say with a Single instead of Completable if the user wants to do more with the value that was saved to the db. If the OP wants more then the OP can comment.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `subscribeOn`? If you use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and don't use `observeOn` above `doOnNext` your code will be executed in IO thread.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .flatMap(value -> Observable.just(value)
                .mergeWith(Completable
                        .fromAction(() -> longOperation(value))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())))
        .subscribe(finalConsumer(it));
```